# Explain why the residue theorem works

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying for a midterm and my teacher warned this would be a good question to understand for the test.  The problem is, I do not know how to go about explaining it.

Suppose $g(x)$ has a pole of order $2$ at the point z. Explain why:

$$\textrm{Res}(g;z)= \lim_{x\to z} \frac{d}{dx}((x-z)^2 g(x))$$